# CUDA Error - Semantic Segmentation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, deep-learning, image-segmentation

Using semantic segmentation, I want to separate the satellite image into two classes: `water` and `land`. I am having this problem:

> An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED

Here is my code:

```
clear;clc;close all

dataDir = fullfile('C:\Users\firat\Desktop\TEZ\Uygulama\Semantic 
Segmentation\data');
imDir = fullfile(dataDir,'image');
pxDir = fullfile(dataDir,'imagePixelLabels');

imds = imageDatastore(imDir);

I = readimage(imds,1);
figure
imshow(I)

% imageLabeler(imDir);

classNames = ["Water" "Land"];
pixelLabelID = [1 2];
pxds = pixelLabelDatastore(pxDir,classNames,pixelLabelID);

C = readimage(pxds,1);

B = labeloverlay(I,C);
figure
imshow(B)

buildingMask = C == 'Water';
figure
imshowpair(I, buildingMask,'montage')

% Create a Semantic Segmentation Network

numFilters = 64;
filterSize = 3;
numClasses = 2;
layers = [
imageInputLayer([1024 1024 3])
convolution2dLayer(filterSize,numFilters,'Padding',1)
reluLayer()
maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)
convolution2dLayer(filterSize,numFilters,'Padding',1)
reluLayer()
transposedConv2dLayer(4,numFilters,'Stride',2,'Cropping',1);
convolution2dLayer(1,numClasses);
softmaxLayer()
pixelClassificationLayer()
]

opts = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
'InitialLearnRate', 1e-3, ...
'MaxEpochs', 100, ...
'MiniBatchSize', 64);

trainingData = pixelLabelImageSource(imds,pxds);

net = trainNetwork(trainingData,layers,opts);

testImage = imread('C:\Users\firat\Desktop\TEZ\Uygulama\Semantic 
Segmentation\test\test3.tif');

C = semanticseg(testImage,net);
B = labeloverlay(testImage,C);
figure
imshow(B)
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some sort of CUDA setup issue. What is output of:

```
gpuDevice()
```

Answer (score 0):

gpuDevice()

```
CUDADevice with properties:
                  Name: 'GeForce 840M'
                 Index: 1.00
     ComputeCapability: '5.0'
        SupportsDouble: 1
         DriverVersion: 9.00
        ToolkitVersion: 8.00
    MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024.00
      MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152.00
    MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024.00 1024.00 64.00]
           MaxGridSize: [2147483647.00 65535.00 65535.00]
             SIMDWidth: 32.00
           TotalMemory: 2147483648.00
   MultiprocessorCount: 3.00
          ClockRateKHz: 1124000.00
           ComputeMode: 'Default'
  GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
      CanMapHostMemory: 1
       DeviceSupported: 1
        DeviceSelected: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease MiniBatchSize as '2' and try again. The problem may be caused by the memory.